# The difference between Parse and Convert in SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query like this

```
SELECT ISDATE('18 Mar 2016 18:57:35 GMT');
```

And it returns 0 of course because the string is not a valid date format and again for the same reason when I run

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '18 Mar 2016 18:57:35 GMT')
```

I get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

But what I do not understand is that why I can do the same with `PARSE` function.

```
SELECT PARSE('18 Mar 2016 18:57:35 GMT' AS DATETIME )
```

I get `2016-03-18 14:57:35.000` as the result.

Can anyone please tell me how `PARSE` and `CONVERT` are different and why I am able to run the query with `PARSE` and not with `CONVERT`? Thanks

Comment: [`CAST` and `CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.120%29.aspx), [`PARSE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213316%28v=sql.120%29.aspx).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The PARSE function is new in SQL Server 2012 and uses the .NET CLR - It's not native T-SQL, while the CONVERT function is native T-SQL.  There might be some performance overhead when using the PARSE function and it also depends on the presence of .NET CLR on your database server.

A quote from http://sqlhints.com/tag/convert-vs-parse/ :

> PARSE function will successfully converts the string ‘Saturday, 08
>   June 2013’ to date time, but the CONVERT function fails to convert the
>   same value. That is PARSE function tries it’s best to convert the
>   input string value to the requested type, but CONVERT function
>   requires the input string to be exact format no variations allowed.

Check out the article for more information:
http://sqlhints.com/tag/convert-vs-parse/

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DATE VARCHAR(30)='18 Mar 2016 18:57:35 GMT'
    SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME,REPLACE(@DATE,'GMT',''))
    PRINT @DATE
```

Because, here GMT string cannot be converted into date time format using `CONVERT()`